# What does 100% really do? (multiple-case study)

Tags: html, css, width, percentage

I'm currently building a fully responsive website, and the more I try to understand, the more I don't. Principally with percentages.

I know a % is based on the first positioned parent. But, I have made some example on JSFiddle, and I had different results:

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfyd2j0p/1/)

In all examples we have the same base:

#### HTML:

```
<div class="example">  
  <div class="container">  
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>   
</div>
```

#### CSS Properties of `div`s :

1. The `.example` block has `position: relative`. It has a `width: 60%` (of his parent: body).
2. The `.container` block has `position: static`. It has a width: 80% (this time of `.example` because it's a relative block).

#### My Problem:

When I want to move the `.item` block instead of `.example` size, but for each CSS attribute I'm using (`margin-left`, `left`, `transform`, etc.), 100% results in a different size. Furthermore, if I change the positioning for `.item` (`static`, `relative`, etc.) the size is different again.

Can someone explain why 100% on `.item` are different for `margin`, `left`, or `transform` ?

Comment: **CASCADING** style sheets. Rules "above" set baseline values for "lower" rules, and the values/calculations cascade downwards. If you have a container set to 1000px wide, and a child within that set to 80%, then the child's effective/calculated size will be 800px. Doing 100% -> 50% -> 33% is making that grandchild element be effectively `1.0 * 0.5 * .33 -> 0.165 -> 16.5%`  of the original grandparent's element's size, or just 33% of the parent's size, which itself is 1/2 of the grandparent's.

Comment: Yeah, but here all my .item have the same xpath : .example .container .item.. But 100% are all the time different, and parent size never change.

Comment: `I know a % is based on the first parent with a relative position` That statement is not true necessarily. In fact a positioned element establishes a containing block for elements having `position` of `absolute`. That's it. Not true for all elements.

Comment: You don't answer to the question, why 100% on .item are different for margin, left, ou transform ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to clarify for you take in care that `%` percentage is not the same computed value for all properties:

With your example the default position is this:

[image]

- In position using `left`

  ```
  Percentages of the width of the containing block
  ```

  In this case since you are using `absolute` position the referent parent is the closest with a non static position defined. "example" container who is defined relative.

  [image]
- In `margin`

  ```
  Percentages refer to the width of the containing block
  ```

  In case one without `absolute` position is fine moving the element to the left exact the size of the `container` div from his initial position.

  [image]

  When you add `absolute` now is the 100% of `example` after the space of his initial position.

  [image]
- In `transform`

  ```
  Percentages refer to the size of bounding box
  ```

  So the element is offset by an amount equal to his width.

  [image]

Comment: This answer deserves more than one +1. Great job, I didn't feel to post such complete answer.

Comment: Thanks @HashemQolami I just think that this is a real good question...maybe the OP have little mistakes on the formulation but deserves an answer % can be a tricky concept in CSS

Comment: I'm realy sorry for the formulation but i don't speak english very well. Whatever, a big thank you for this reply !

Comment: Just remembered that Louis Lazaris has wrote an article about "[Vertical Percentages in CSS](http://www.impressivewebs.com/vertical-percentages-css/)". It might help somebody.

Comment: @Arthur np mate I catch the Idea glad to help u