# HTML top margin by percentage

Tags: html, css, percentage

Is there any reason why a div set to a height of 1000px should not be able to accept percentages for the top margin? This code demonstrates the issue:

```
    <html>
    <body>
        <div style='height: 1000px; margin-top: 50%; font-size: 30pt;'>
            this is displayed at the bottom of the 1920 x 1080 monitor...
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Why isn't the text displayed somewhere in the middle of a 1920 x 1080 monitor instead of at its bottom?

Comment: The size of the monitor doesn't matter.  50% of 1000px is 500px, so if your monitor-view-port is only showing 700-ish pixels, the div being 500px below the top of the browser window will look like it's closer to the bottom.

Comment: @Gerwin: *margin-top* clearly implies that the *1000px* is the height of the div; in addition, the code clearly indicates it. So, it isn't a grammatical error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `%` values on margin doesn't refer to the `height` of the element.

> Refer to the width of the containing block

In this case will be the `width` of the `body`  tag.

With the next snippet you can try open in full page and resize the width of your browser you will see the margin-top changes based on that.

```css
body {background:#eee;}
div {background:#ccc;}
```

```html
<div style='height: 1000px; margin-top: 50%; font-size: 30pt;'>
  this is displayed at the bottom of the 1920 x 1080 monitor...
</div>
```

---

#### This Another Question Can clarify for you the use of % In some CSS properties

#### <kbd>https://stackoverflow.com/a/26412875/2887133</kbd>

Comment: Thank you, Danko; especially for your detailed answer. I never knew that!

Answer (score 2):

You can use "vh" instead of "%". Try setting:

```
<div style='height: 1000px; margin-top: 50vh; font-size: 30pt;'>
```

This will set the top margin to 50% of the viewport (browser window in your case).

Comment: Thanks Mike. Your *vh* suggestion solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Margin is working as expected. As you're applying margin-top: 50%; it goes downwards 50% so it is in bottom rather than centered. You need to do like this to center:

```
<div style='height: 1000px; position: relative; top:50%; margin-top: -500px; font-size: 30pt;'>
```